# The set $C=\{x\in A: x\in A_n\space\text{at least two n's}\}$ has measure $\mu(C)\leq\epsilon.$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm proving the next:

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ with $A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{n})\leq\mu(A)+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0.$ Prove that

i)$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E\cap A_{n})\leq\mu(E\cap A)+\epsilon$ for all $E\in\mathcal{F}.$

ii) Let $C=\{x\in A: x\in A_n\space\text{at least two n's}\},$ then $C\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\mu(C)\leq\epsilon.$

I've proved i) utilizing the fact that there is a measurable disjoint sequence of sets $\{E_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}=A.$

My problem comes on ii). Measurable si clear because $C=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n,m=1, n\neq m}^{\infty}A_{n}\cap A_{m},$ but I can't see why $\mu(C)\leq\epsilon.$

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu (A_n \cap ({A_{n-1} \cup ...\cup A_1))}=\mu (A_n) -\mu (B_n)$ where $B_n=A_n - A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...\cup A_{n-1}$. Note that C is containe din the union of the sets $(A_n \cap ({A_{n-1} \cup ...\cup A_1))}$. It follows that $\mu (C) \leq \sum \{\mu (A_n) -\mu (B_n)\}<\mu(A)+ \epsilon -\mu (A)= \epsilon$. I have used the fact that $B_n$'s are disjoint sets whose union is A.

Comment: What a clever proof!! Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy.